# How to download file using Firefox Headless?

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to download a XML file from specific website using selenium and Firefox Headless, but I'm not having success.

Also, If possible I need to save de downloaded file into specific folder.

Can Anyone Helps me?

Here is where I initializate my Firefox Driver:

```
    public static FirefoxDriver callFirefox()
    {
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.AddArgument("--headless");

        FirefoxDriver firefox = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        return firefox;
    }
```

And here, the other part of code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var ff = callFirefox();
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)ff;

            ff.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://tracking.estrada.com.br/index.asp");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            ff.FindElementById("usuario").SendKeys("XXXXXXX");
            ff.FindElementByName("senha").SendKeys("XXXXXXX");
            js.ExecuteScript("submitform();");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            //CHANGE THE FRAME
            ff.SwitchTo().Frame(0);

            ff.FindElements(By.Id("f_dataini")).FirstOrDefault().SendKeys("20122018");
            ff.FindElements(By.Id("f_datafin")).FirstOrDefault().SendKeys("26122018");

            js.ExecuteScript("Exportar_XML();");

            Console.WriteLine("CONCLUIDO");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

In this website, after execute the Function `js.ExecuteScript("Exportar_XML();");` the browser starts the download of XML file.

Comment: You'll get much better results if you used something like Fiddler/Wireshark to capture packets and login/export via direct calls versus trying to use a browser along with waiting/sending keys/calling Javascript.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/53962374/797495

Comment: @PedroLobito this one doesnt works in Headless mode.