# How can I add extra_capabilities for firefox to test with selenium using perl?

Tags: perl, selenium, firefox, download

I have been able to set this parameters like download folder and prompt for download in the following manner (Or similar, as I don't have that code right know):

```
 'extra_capabilities' => {
   'chromeOptions' => {
       'prefs' => {
           'download.default_directory' => '/Users/User/Desktop/my_folder',
           "download.prompt_for_download" => 0,
           "download.directory_upgrade" => 1,
       }
   },
   'binaray' => '/Users/User/Applications/Chromium',
```

}

I've been trying to do the same with firefox but I have not been able to get those properties anywhere. The only code I've found in other questions is for java using some profile objects which I think it's not available for perl.

This is a simplified version of my attempt but it doesn't seem to work. But it does not generate an exception either:

```
use Selenium::Firefox;
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Selenium::Waiter qw/wait_until/;
$Selenium::Remote::Driver::FORCE_WD3=1;

my $driver = Selenium::Firefox->new(marionette_enabled => 1,
                                    capabilities => {
                                      "browser.download.folderList" => 2,
                                      "browser.helperapps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" => "tcx",
                                      "browser.download.dir" => '/Users/User/Desktop/myFolder/'
                                    } );
$driver->set_implicit_wait_timeout(3000);

my $url_to_download = "http://blablabla.com/blabla.tcx";
$driver->get($url_to_download);

$driver->quit();
$driver->shutdown_binary();
```

Comment: The tests suggest that you can just use `extra_capabilities` with Selenium::Firefox as well ( https://grep.metacpan.org/search?qci=&q=extra_capabilities&qft=&qd=Selenium-Remote-Driver&f=at%2Ffirefox.test )

Comment: For some reason, I was not aware of the grep metacpan site. That's a really useful resource, Thanks @Corion

Comment: They say with chrome `'goog:chromeOptions'` is better (than `'chromeOptions'`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @Corion I've been able to make it work. This is the code I've used to create the driver:

```
my $driver = Selenium::Firefox->new(marionette_enabled => 1,
                                    extra_capabilities => {
                                      'moz:firefoxOptions' => {
                                        'prefs' => {
                                          "browser.download.folderList" => 2,
                                          "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" => "application/tcx+xml",
                                          "browser.download.dir" => '/Users/User/Desktop/myFolder/'
                                        }
                                      }
                                    } );
```

In order to get the "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" property just use the network inspector manually and get the content-type of the response.